# Pocketsphinx Accuracy

Tags: php, audio, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

Im extracting the first 15 seconds of this video 
https://thenewboston.com/videos.php?cat=49&video=18983
and heres what i get as output

> are italy's engine little while to cheer for it to my eyes to look store or in now that we have so that it play with
>   go adam play with a soul open up php my aunt and my of course clicking the link and once you do your php

which is *exactly not* what its said in the video(see subtitles from youtube)

I installed the Sphinxbase and Pocketsphinx from [here](http://jrmeyer.github.io/installation/2016/01/09/Installing-CMU-Sphinx-on-Ubuntu.html)

I tried these commands, but every time I'm getting something different.

```
pocketsphinx_continuous -infile  /var/www/html/music/videoaudio.wav
hmm model/cmusphinx-en-us-5.2 -lm model/en-70k-0.2.lm/en-70k-0.2.lm > /var/www/html/music/videoaudio.txt
pocketsphinx_continuous -infile /var/www/html/music/videoaudio.wav > /var/www/html/music/videoaudio.txt
```

Models are [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/US%20English/)

My Problem is that I don't quite understand how to use Acoustic/Language Models and get accurate results or *at least near accurate*.

Comment: The audio to process must be 16khz 16bit mono wav file. You can use the command `ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -ar 16000 -ac 1 file.wav` to create the file in proper format. Your videoaudio.wav is most likely wrong format.

Comment: It returns `let him play with it so open up php man in my of course clicking the link it was you do your php my mentor should open up now on my school had answer some really simple commands now in order to type in these commands you always go up to this s que el cap no one every clicking you have this text box of opens up a mrs were in your in your commands solace or something very simple pipe`. It's pretty accurate except it doesn't know words like 'SQL' or database. Language model adaptation for this purpose is explained here: http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutoriallmadvanced

Comment: `ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/music/file.mp4  -vn -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -ar 16000 -ss 0 -t 30 /var/www/html/music/file.wav` . This is how i converted the video

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev what is the language/acoustic model youre using ? whats the link ? maybe im using the wrong ones

Comment: You can use default models coming with pocketsphinx, simply `pocketsphinx_continuous -infile file.wav`. Just make sure you have latest pocketsphinx you start from /usr/local/bin, it might be that you have older version installed.

Comment: You should get `ari ladies and gentlemen welcome to your fourth miners who looks or old and now that we have so that a play with
let him play with it so open up php man in my of course clicking the link it was you do your php my mentor should open up now on my school had answer some really simple commands now in order to type in these commands you always go up to this s que el cap no one every clicking you have this text box of opens up to`

Comment: So how do i make the sphinx understand the words like `sql` and database etc ? @NikolayShmyrev

Comment: link on tutorial is above

Comment: In my experience the issue with PocketSphinx is that the words to word-sounds (called phones) mapping it comes with out of the box is too large. One way to make some progress is to reduce the number of words PocketSphinx is expecting by reducing the size of this dictionary. CMU provide a tool to do exactly this at http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/tools/lextool.html